# Zone doesn't work with Q&A under Admin

Tags: chatter-answers, community, zone

Zone was created for community but Q&A tab dosn't show any questions but shows error message :

```
You do not have access to any Chatter Answers zones.
```

It seems that some changes from summer 14 deployment affects this because it worked before summer 14 release.

Comment: This link works for me: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205591&language=en_US